# How can i excute script New page in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I make chrome extension.
this program read now page and anlysis it, go to next page.

I already made read and goto next page. but there a problem.
read now page and move next page is perfect. but next page, read function isn't work.

I click read button on first page, read it. but move next and read, not work.

i see callback function get **undefined** data.

below is my code.

```
function matching(user) {
    JustFIDsFromPage(); 
}
function JustFindIDsFromPage() {
    //read and find Data
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: "var ids = [];var names = document.querySelector('.gallery').children;for(var i=0;i<names.length;i++){var tmp = names[i].innerHTML;var id = tmp.substring(11+tmp.search('/galleries/'),tmp.search('.html'));ids.push(id)} ids"
    }, callbackJustFindIDsFromPage);

}

function callbackJustFindIDsFromPage(count) {
    //save get datas.
    var idList = count.toString().split(',');
    for (var i = 0; i < idList.length; i++) {
        document.querySelector('#result').innerText += idList[i] + "\n";
    }
    //go to next page.
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: "var page = document.querySelector('.page').firstElementChild.children; var end=0; var inhtml = page[1].innerHTML;var intext = page[1].innerText; if(inhtml == intext){var link = page[2].innerHTML; var url = link.substring(9, 20); end=1; window.location.href = url; } end;"
    }, callbackGoNextPage);

}

function callbackGoNextPage(nextFlag) {
    if (nextFlag == 1) {
        JustFindIDsFromPage();
    }
}
```

I guess this.

chrome.tabs.executeScript just excute on 'first' open page.

I don't know what is real. please help me!

Comment: have you tried tampermonkey?

Comment: @Josh Lin  I listen for the first time. but this look like extension. this program can run my script? that's nice.
but, if not impossible, i want make own extension.

Comment: First, use debugger in devtools and you'll see the callback receives an array, so it's never 1. Second, use chrome.tabs.onUpdated to wait for the tab to load, you can find examples.

Comment: @wOxxOm it will work for me. thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code will work for you.

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tabss) {
    tabid = tabss.TAB_ID_NONE;
});

chrome.tabs.update(tabid, { url: url, active: true }, function (tab1) {

var listener = function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

    if (tabId == tab1.id && changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
       chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(listener);
        //your code

        }
    }
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(listener);
 });
```